# vCloud Director sdk for PHP

Tags: php, api, sdk, cloud, vmware

Has anyone managed to initiate a vApp template and then assign an IP and computer name to the associated VM via the vCloud Director API using the PHP SDK?

I have been able to initiate the vApp template and get the VM running. But always get a System Alert saying Guest Customization failed due to missing Reconfig Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the fact that vCloud Director required all network config parameters such as IP ranges to be managed by itself. You cannot assign an IP that is not known to vCloud Director.

By creating known IP ranges within vCloud Director resolved the problem.